# Prevent NFC token from being easily copied?

Tags: countermeasure, nfc

From my knowledge on NFC, which isn't a lot, it seems like it would be very easy to copy an NFC token.

What methods can be used to prevent people from making unauthorised copies of the NFC tokens?

When I say tokens I mean the ones found in for entry fobs and on advertising etc.. the ones that are in a constant state.

Comment: potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/is-it-possible-to-clone-an-rfid-nfc-card-using-a-simple-rfid-reader-for-future

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. My question asks how to prevent it rather if it is possible to duplicate.

Comment: the answer there answers you here: PKI, rotating codes

Comment: you can't; it's basically a barcode without the bars...