# How to prevent contactless cards RFID signal cloning

Tags: credit-card, rfid

I have always been sceptical about contactless. It offers little security. I've even heard of cases where the RFID signal has been captured onto mobile devices. My questions are.

1. Is there anything stopping actors who could capture the RFID signal using it a second time? such as a part of the data in the signal changing each time?
2. What is the best way to stop signals leaking? I can only think of;

- Incision into the card through the RFID circuit.
- Wrapping the card in foil inside the wallet.
- Using a wallet that blocks RFID

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to clone an RFID/NFC card using a simple RFID reader, for future reuse and impersonation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/is-it-possible-to-clone-an-rfid-nfc-card-using-a-simple-rfid-reader-for-future), [How can RFID/NFC tags not be cloned when they are passive technology?](/questions/131638/)

Comment: It answers part one of the question thank you, but not part 2 about user mitigation.

Comment: It is a recommended to keep questions to a single point and not put everything one wants to know about a topic into a single question. I recommend that you ask what is remaining in another question - but maybe it is also answered by [Can a steel woven wallet prevent RFID scanning of credit card information?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43321/can-a-steel-woven-wallet-prevent-rfid-scanning-of-credit-card-information).

Comment: Thanks. I think I will get RFID disabled if I can, looks quite a risk.